# How to create a sql server staging/testing environment that is kept somewhat up-to-date with production?

Tags: sql-server

We have a couple production SQL Server machines running something like 50 database catalogs that are used by a number of applications.

Right now we have a dev sql server that has copies of all these database catalogs for us to develop against, but what I'd really like is for another server to be a "staging" or "test" environment that closely mirrors our production environment.

Ideally, we like to have something that can automate the process of duplicating a production database.  I assume our best option would be some type of scripted restore of production backup files, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Could you specify what sql server edition you have for your production and intended-staging databases? Also, what kind of data redundancy do you already practice in your production databases? Oh, and by closely mirroring the production databases, could you be specific --in terms of data structure and/or data and/or load handling etc? :)

Comment: We have SQL Server 2008 R2 on all database servers, except for 1 of our prod servers, that is running sql server 2000.  We haven't been able to migrate our last 2 databases from the 2000 server.  I think at some point we are going to finally migrate those, but there are many cross server and cross catalog queries that reference those 2 catalogs that it's a pretty big job to move those 2.

Comment: Oh, and we'd want both structure and data.  We have some issues from time to time where stuff works in dev, but we find an issue in production because of some different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't simply automate the backup restoration of the last production backup to a test server as a scheduled task?

Comment: I'm not fully sure.  I *think* in the past our problem had to do with the number of SPs and Views that were doing cross database/cross catalog queries in the source databases.  I guess that wouldn't prevent a restore from completing, and we'd need to recreate the SPs and Views that had 3 and 4 part naming conventions for tables to use a synonym (for the source database catalogs that are in sql server 2000).